# Is it possible to find the term (variable) $c$ from the equation $a^2=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the equation $a^2=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$. Is it possible to me to find the term (variable) $c$ from it ?

> $c=\,?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply talking about re-arranging the equation?

$$\left(a^{2}\right)^{2}=\left(\sqrt{b^{2}+c^{2}}\right)^{2}\implies a^{4}=b^{2}+c^{2}\implies c^{2}=a^{4}-b^{2} \implies c = \pm\sqrt{a^{4}-b^{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you that's what I'm looking for, but my English is bad :)